# 3rd Conditional use as Future Perfect possible?

Tags: conditionals

> If I **found** a wallet on the street I **would bring** it to the police

Here the speaker is talking about an imaginary situation in the future, both of the actions are in the future and thus the speaker uses 2nd conditional.

3rd conditional, however,  refers to the past and thus is equal to Past Simple, Present Perfect and Past Perfect tenses. My question is: Can 3rd Conditional be used in the meaning of Future Perfect?
Is it possible to say

> "If I **had found** a wallet on the street, **I would bring** in to
> the police"

on the basis that "bring" is an action in the future and "had found" precedes that action, (both of them are in the future, though) thus using the main function of Future Perfect.

I got this idea when I was thinking about modal verbs and their past usage (i.e. should have done) which can also be used not only as past, but also to imitate Future Perfect (we'll get there at 7, by that time he should've finished the job)

Comment: That sentence neither *3rd conditional*, nor does it have the function of *future perfect*. Please look up what those terms mean and edit your question to make it clear what you're really asking. Also, I've removed your second question as more than one question in one is off-topic.

Comment: "If I had found", in fact, IS 3rd conditional, while  "would bring" is 2nd.
the "would-clause" of the 3rd conditional (would + have + V3) can perform not only the functions of past tenses but also that of the Future Perfect tense. "If I won a tennis tournament, I would have beaten at least 10 opponents"
My question was, can the same logic be applied to the "if-clause" of the 3rd conditional?
But I already got the answer, for the most part

Comment: No. 3rd conditional is the entire structure ***If** I **had found** a wallet on the street, I **would have brought** it to the police.* If you change any part of that grammar, it is no longer 3rd conditional.

Comment: The interesting thing is that you can use *"will have done"* to talk about a real past possibility. E.g., *"I don't know what train John caught **yesterday.** If he **caught** the 18.42 (possibility), he **will have arrived** home before midnight".* The midnight that is already in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Take* or *hand in* would be more natural verbs than *bring.*

In the past tense, you would say

> If I **had found** a wallet in the street, I **would have taken** it to the police.

Comment: so I can't say "If I had found" when talking about the future? Would it be a mistake?

Comment: @Mr.PastProgressive If I find a wallet, I will take it to the police. Even so, that is not really a future. All these are conditions contrary to fact.

Comment: **If I found** isn't really talking about the future, but about a hypothetical situation. **If I had found** could refer either to the past or  to a hypothetical present - 'If I were in the situation of having found a wallet...'

Comment: If I understood your correctly,  "If I HAD FOUND + I WOULD BRING" would mean 
"If I were in a situation of having just found a wallet, my next action would be to hand it to the police" is that right? Would that sentence be correct?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any difference in meaning between "If I had found..  I would bring.." and "If I found.. I would bring.." ?

Comment: No, I don't think so - but, unless you were in the police station talking to an officer, you would say _take_ not _bring_.

Comment: I've also noticed that in your 1st post you said that "if I found" is a hypothetical situation and doesn't really refer to the future. I always thought it refers to hypothetical future. (the one the speaker doesn't really expect or plan to fulfill")

Is it possible to say "If I won a lottery tomorrow, I would buy a large house a couple of days later"? Wouldn't both parts be hypothetical future here?

Comment: Well, a hypothetical situation could be called 'the future' in that it hasn't happened yet, but not in the sense that it is predicted to happen.